# How do I check on non-transparent pixels in a bitmapdata?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, pixel, masking

I'm still working on my window cleaning game from [one of my previous questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/as3-flash-how-to-check-if-a-bitmapdata-is-completely-set-to-transparent-using-an)

I marked a contribution as my answer, but after all this time I can't get it to work and I have to many questions about this so I decided to ask some more about it. As a sequel on my mentioned previous question, my question to you is:

How can I check whether or not a bitmapData contains non transparent pixels? 
Subquestion: Is this possible when the masked image is a movieclip? Shouldn't I use graphics instead?

**Information**
I have: A dirtywindow movieclip on the bottom layer and a clean window movieclip on layer 2(mc1) on the layer above.

To hide the top layer(the dirty window) I assign a mask to it.

**Code**

```
// this creates a mask that hides the movieclip on top
var mask_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(mask_mc)

//assign the mask to the movieclip it should 'cover'
mc1.mask = mask_mc;

With a brush(cursor) the player wipes of the dirt ( actualy setting the fill from the mask to transparent so the clean window appears)

//add event listeners for the 'brush'
brush_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,brushDown);
brush_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,brushUp);

//function to drag the brush over the mask
function brushDown(dragging:MouseEvent):void{
    dragging.currentTarget.startDrag();
    MovieClip(dragging.currentTarget).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,erase) ;
    mask_mc.graphics.moveTo(brush_mc.x,brush_mc.y);
}

//function to stop dragging the brush over the mask
function brushUp(dragging:MouseEvent):void{
    dragging.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    MovieClip(dragging.currentTarget).removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,erase);
}

//fill the mask with transparant pixels so the movieclip turns visible
function erase(e:Event):void{
    with(mask_mc.graphics){
        beginFill(0x000000);
        drawRect(brush_mc.x,brush_mc.y,brush_mc.width,brush_mc.height);
        endFill(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Since your question is already tagged with [tag:actionscript-3], you don't need to also dump the tag in your question's title - I've edited it out.

Answer (score 4):

You're not working with bitmaps here. The `graphics` object you're using uses vector graphics. So basically you're painting a lot of rectangles to your mask...

The only reasonable way to determine whether or not your mask is entirely filled would be to render it to a `BitmapData` (using `BitmapData.draw`) and then iterate through the pixels until you hit a transparent one. In that case your mask still contains transparent parts. If you checked all pixels without hitting a transparent pixel, your mask is completely filled.

This seems overly complicated though. I'd work on a Bitmap right from the start (eg. your "dirty" layer is a bitmap on top of your clean MovieClip. Then you actually erase the dirty pixels instead of using a mask.

**Update:** I did a quick test of the Bitmap based approach. Here's the [result](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1352293262) (there's an indicator circle that always jumps to the first non-transparent pixel. Otherwise it would be too difficult to find all the pixels). And here's the [source-code](http://pastie.org/5340725).